# Compatibility of monoid and comonoid structures when monoidal product is a product

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category with finite products.  Then $\mathcal{C}$ is a braided monoidal category with the product as the monoidal product and terminal object as the monoidal unit, and braiding $\tau_{A,B}$ the unique isomorphism $A\times B \cong B\times A$ induced since both of sides are the product of $A$ and $B$.  For every object $A$ in $\mathcal{C}$, $A$ has the unique structure of a comonoid with comultiplication given by the diagonal map, $\Delta$, and counit the unique map to the terminal object. Now suppose $A$ is a monoidal object with multiplication $\mu$.  I'd like to show that the monoidal and comonoidal structures are compatible in the sense that $\Delta$ is a monoid morphism.  This is part of the justification for calling Hopf algebras "group objects" in braided monoidal categories.  I'm stuck trying to show that $\Delta\circ\mu = \mu\times\mu\circ(\text{id}\times\tau\times\text{id})\circ \Delta \times \Delta$.

Comment: By Yoneda Lemma (olr evalutation by representables) you can put $\mathcal{C}=Set$, now a monoid is a usual algebraic monoid, and is trivial see that $\Delta$ is a monoid morphism.

Answer (score 3):

This has very little to do with monoidal categories and much more to do with the properties of the cartesian product (and, very specifically, $\Delta$). Observe:

$$\begin{split}
\Delta(\mu(x, y)) & = (\mu(x, y), \mu(x, y)) \\
& = (\mu \times \mu) (x, y, x, y) \\
& = ((\mu \times \mu) \circ (\textrm{id} \times \tau \times \textrm{id})) (x, x, y, y) \\
& = ((\mu \times \mu) \circ (\textrm{id} \times \tau \times \textrm{id}) \circ (\Delta \times \Delta)) (x, y)
\end{split}$$

You can interpret $x$ and $y$ as generalised elements $U \to A$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I've never heard of generalized elements before.  Are you saying that we can use generalized elements to reduce the problem to a proof that the property holds in the category of sets with Cartesian product?  I tried looking online on Wikipedia and nLab, but so far haven't been able to understand how generalized elements work yet.  Is there a good reference for this?  Is it in Maclane?

Comment: -ish. Roughly speaking, what we are doing is taking the Yoneda representation of a category. Then a morphism $U \to A$ genuinely is an "element" – specifically an element of the representable presheaf $\textrm{Hom}(-, A)$. Mac Lane does a special kind of generalised element in Chapter VIII. Lawvere and Rosebrugh [_Sets for mathematics_] also discuss generalised elements a bit.